# LINKERD: Pending External IP in Kubernetes on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, linkerd

[image]

I have installed kubernetes on my ubuntu machine when I tried to run the following command I see external-IP as "pending", where svc.yml is service object in linkerd, link below

link: https://linkerd.io/getting-started/k8s/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The yaml you specified for the Service has `type: LoadBalancer`. That will only work with a cloud provider - so not on your bare metal Ubuntu installation.

Modify the Service definition and specify a different type, for example [clusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#publishing-services---service-types)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have insufficient memory on your machine, try this command

**kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep '\sname\|cpu\|memory'**

reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/debugging-pods-and-replication-controllers/

Comment: This is not the problem in this case. The Service itself is pending state, not pods. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you are using `LoadBalancer` on an on-premise / bare-metal kubernetes cluster.

https://github.com/google/metallb

From the [project description](https://metallb.universe.tf/):

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers (Services of type LoadBalancer) for bare metal clusters. ... If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers **will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created**.

and this project tries to solve this problem.